# How to get the row in which a value is found foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array in which I'm using nested foreach loops to loop through to find someone's first and last name. Once I find the value, I need to note which row those values were found in. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I go about doing this?

```
foreach($finalArray as $value){
    foreach($value as $key => $value2){         
        if ($value2 == $firstname){
            $firstnameFound = "true";
            if($value2 == $lastname)
                $lastnameFound = "true";
        }
        $colNumber = $key;  
    }   
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP but based on the documentation here (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) you can use the $key to accomplish this by storing it in a separate variable. I would create another variable, perhaps an integer called "firstNamePosition" and set it to $key's value. Same for last name. Then you can do something like $finalArray(firstNamePosition) and $finalArray(lastNamePosition) to access the elements at their position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is a little confusing, since you compare both `$firstname` and `$lastname` to `$value2` (implying that they would have to be the same for the search to be successful). You also store the column in `$colnumber` outside of the if statement, which means that it will just end up being assigned to the last column in the for loop.

The use of the `=>` symbol is important, since that gives you access to the index of the array you are iterating through (your row or column). Here is a boilerplate example that you can work off for your own needs, assuming that `table` is a two-dimensional array of strings and you want the row and column of the table that has the string "John".

```
$foundRow = $foundCol = NULL;
foreach ($table as $rowIndex => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $colIndex => $name) {
        if ($name == "John") {
            $foundRow = $rowIndex;
            $foundCol = $colIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how we assign `$foundRow` and `$foundCol` in the if statement. The row and col where "John" was found are now stored in `$foundRow` and `$foundCol` respectively, unless "John" was not in the 2D array, in which case both variables are `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code as the basis, you can use the following:

```
foreach($finalArray as $key0 => $value){
    foreach($value as $key => $value2){
        if ($value2 == $firstname){
            $col1 = $key0;
            $col2 = $key;
        }
    }
}
```

Working code at [eval.in](https://eval.in/485169).

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_keys()`  to get the Key name of your array:

```
 foreach(array_keys($finalArray) as $key){

     $column = $key; //key name
     $value = $finalArray[$column]; //value of the key

    ...//you algo here.

}
```

Can you atleast complete your codes not exactly all of it, but make it clear when asking question. I don't know where your variable came from.